# How to find a suitable function for Dulac's criteria in this example?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

I have a system of odes $\dot{\mathbf{x}} = \mathbf{f(x)}$ where $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $\mathbf{f(x)}$ is defined below:

$$\dot{x} = x- y - x^{3}, \qquad \dot{y} = x+y-y^{3}$$

I would like to apply Dulac's criteria to show that there is a limit cycle in the annulus  $1 < || \mathbf{x}|| < \sqrt{2}$. Thus, I try to find a function $B(x,y) \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ such that $\nabla \cdot (B \mathbf{f})$ is not identically zero or change signs in a region $E = \{\mathbf{x}: 0 \leq ||\mathbf{x}||< \sqrt{2} \}$.

How could I obtain a suitable test function $B$ for this?

Comment: Two things : 1) why do you call the set  $\{\mathbf{x}: 0 \leq \mathbf{x}< \sqrt{2} \}$ an annulus ? For me it is a stripe. 2) I had a look at Dulac's criteria (that honestly I didn't know) but it looks like it is a criteria for ruling out the existence of a limit cycle ...

Comment: An annulus for $1< \mathbf{x} < \sqrt{2}$ since $ \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$, i.e. $\mathbf{x}$ is a vector.  The first part of Dulac says that simply for a simply connected region $E$ there is no colsed orbit entirely in $E$ if $\nabla \cdot (B \mathbf{f})$ above holds. There's  also a second part of Dulac's criteria that states if $A$ is an annular region in $E$, there is at most one limit cycle. The point is that the annulus is $\textit{not}$ simply connected... @JeanMarie

Comment: Sorry, I made a confusion between bold $\mathbf{x}$ and $x$. (This confusion is a little due to the lack of norm signs in $\{\mathbf{x}: 0 \leq \|\mathbf{x}\|< \sqrt{2} \}$. Thank you for the  precision about the different parts of Dulac's criteria.

Comment: The norm signs have been edited now.  @JeanMarie

Comment: As an aside, due to the fact that $E$ is not simply connected, Bendixson's criteria is not contradicted for this example, and one does indeed have a periodic orbit in $1  \leq || \mathbf{x} || \leq \sqrt{2}$. @JeanMarie

Comment: Thanks again, I understand much more how the issue is linked to a topological property.

Comment: The simplest is the best: $B(x,y)=x^2+y^2$.

Comment: This choice of $B$ gives a change of sign in the specified region, so it does not work. @Did

Comment: What? Note that $\partial_xB\cdot\dot x+\partial_yB\cdot\dot y\geqslant0$ on $x^2+y^2=1$ and $\partial_xB\cdot\dot x+\partial_yB\cdot\dot y\leqslant0$ on $x^2+y^2=2$, do we need anything else?

Comment: Ah ok, yes this is absolutely fine. Indeed in the interior of the specified annulus, the sign is always positive, which is what we wanted. (I meant that for $ 0<  || \mathbf{x} || < 1$ the function $\nabla \cdot (B \mathbf{f})$ can be negative, but that's not what we want.) @Did